# JavaFX gui - can't save data

Tags: sqlite, user-interface, javafx, tableview

i need to make gui who will display all objects from database with auto increment ID. When we will click on some object,and click on edit button,we can edit data like name etc. When we will end change our object,we must click on save button who need update data in database. How i can add an autoincrement ID to database? (i've created one,but without ID) when i added an id to database,i can't display any data on receiveCats.fxml. Second issue that i have is to this save button. How i can push edited data to object in database?

Database class

```
package Database;

import Model.Cats;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;


public class Database {

public static final String Driver = "org.sqlite.JDBC";
public static final String DB_url = "jdbc:sqlite:DB/ShelterDB.db/";

private Connection connection;
private Statement statement;

public Database() {

    try {
        Class.forName(Database.Driver);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("No driver JDBC");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_url);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem with opening the connection");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    createTables();
}

public boolean createTables() {
    String createCats = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Cats (Cat_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name varchar(255), race varchar(255), gender varchar(255), coat_color varchar(255),age int)";
    String createDogs = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Dogs (Dog_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name varchar(255), race varchar(255), gender varchar(255), coat_color varchar(255),age int)";
    String createManagments = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Managment (Managment_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name varchar(255), surname varchar(255), username varchar(255), password varchar(255), telephone_number int)";
    String createEmployes = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employes (Employe_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name varchar(255), surname varchar(255), age int, city varchar(255), street varchar(255), house_number int, education varchar(255), telephone_number int, sallary double)";
    String createStatus = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Status (foodForCats int, foodForDogs int, water int, equipment int, placesForCats int, placesForDogs int)";

    try {
        statement.execute(createCats);
        statement.execute(createDogs);
        statement.execute(createManagments);
        statement.execute(createEmployes);
        statement.execute(createStatus);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem with creating a table");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean insertCat(int id,String name, String race, String gender, String coat_color, int age) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into Cats values (NULL,?,?,?,?,?);");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, race);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, gender);
        preparedStatement.setString(4, coat_color);
        preparedStatement.setInt(5, age);
        preparedStatement.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error with insert an cat to the table");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean insertDog(String name, String race, String gender, String coat_color, int age) {

    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into Dogs values (NULL,?,?,?,?,?);");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, race);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, gender);
        preparedStatement.setString(4, coat_color);
        preparedStatement.setInt(5, age);
        preparedStatement.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error with insert an dog to the table");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean insertManagment(String name, String surname, String username, String password, int telephone_number) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into Managment values (NULL,?,?,?,?,?);");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, surname);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, username);
        preparedStatement.setString(4, password);
        preparedStatement.setInt(5, telephone_number);
        preparedStatement.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error with insert an managment to the table");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean insertEmployes(String name, String surname, int age, String city, String street, int house_number, String education, int telephone_number, double sallary) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into Employees values (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");
        preparedStatement.setString(1,name);
        preparedStatement.setString(2,surname);
        preparedStatement.setInt(3,age);
        preparedStatement.setString(4,city);
        preparedStatement.setString(5,street);
        preparedStatement.setInt(6,house_number);
        preparedStatement.setString(7,education);
        preparedStatement.setInt(8,telephone_number);
        preparedStatement.setDouble(9,sallary);
        preparedStatement.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error with insert an employee to the table");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


public boolean insertStatus(int foodForCats, int foodForDogs, int water, int equipment, int placesForCats, int placesForDogs){
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into status values (?,?,?,?,?,?);");
        preparedStatement.setInt(1,foodForCats);
        preparedStatement.setInt(2,foodForDogs);
        preparedStatement.setInt(3,water);
        preparedStatement.setInt(4,equipment);
        preparedStatement.setInt(5,placesForCats);
        preparedStatement.setInt(6,placesForDogs);
        preparedStatement.execute();
    }catch (SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Error with insert values into Status");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean updateCats(Cats cats){
    try {
        String updateData = "UPDATE Cats SET name=?, race=?, gender=?, coat_color=?, age=?";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(updateData);
        preparedStatement.setString(1,cats.getName());
        preparedStatement.setString(2,cats.getRace());
        preparedStatement.setString(3,cats.getGender());
        preparedStatement.setString(4,cats.getCoatColor());
        preparedStatement.setInt(5,cats.getAge());
        int res = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        return  (res>0);
    }catch (SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Can't update data\n"+e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}

public ResultSet execQuery(String query){
    ResultSet resultSet;
    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
    }catch (SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Error in exec query\n"+e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }finally {
    }
    return resultSet;
}

public boolean execAction(String qu){
    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.execute(qu);
        return true;
    }catch (SQLException e){
        System.out.println("excecption at exec action\n"+e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }finally {

    }
}

public void closeConnection() {
    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Error with shutdown");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Cats model class

```
package Model;



import javafx.beans.property.*;

public class Cats {


public Cats(Integer id,String name, String race, String gender, String coatColor, Integer age) {
    this.id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(id);
    this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    this.race = new SimpleStringProperty(race);
    this.gender = new SimpleStringProperty(gender);
    this.coatColor = new SimpleStringProperty(coatColor);
    this.age = new SimpleIntegerProperty(age);
}

public IntegerProperty id;
public IntegerProperty IDproperty(){return id;}
public Integer getID(){return IDproperty().get();}

public StringProperty name;

public void setName(String value) {
    nameProperty().set(value);
}

public StringProperty nameProperty() {
    return name;
}

public String getName() {
    return nameProperty().get();
}

public StringProperty race;

public void setRace(String value) {
    raceProperty().set(value);
}

public StringProperty raceProperty() {
    return race;
}

public String getRace() {
    return raceProperty().get();
}

public StringProperty gender;

public void setGender(String value) {
    genderProperty().set(value);
}

public StringProperty genderProperty() {
    return gender;
}

public String getGender() {
    return genderProperty().get();
}


public StringProperty coatColor;

public void setCoatColor(String value) {
    coatColorProperty().set(value);
}

public StringProperty coatColorProperty() {
    return coatColor;
}

public String getCoatColor() {
    return coatColorProperty().get();
}


public IntegerProperty age;

public void setAge(Integer value) {
    ageProperty().set(value);
}

public IntegerProperty ageProperty() {
    return age;
}

public Integer getAge() {
    return ageProperty().get();
}

}
```

retrieve cat controller

```
package Animals.Cats.retrieveCats;

import Animals.Cats.editCat.editCatController;
import Database.Database;

import Model.Cats;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class retrieveCatsController implements Initializable {

    ObservableList<Cats> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane tableRootPanel; //?

    @FXML
    private TableView<Cats> tableView;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Cats,Integer> catsId;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Cats, String> catsName;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Cats, String> catsRace;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Cats, String> catsGender;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Cats, String> catsCoatColor;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Cats, Integer> catsAge;

    public void editCats(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        Cats editSelectedCat = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (editSelectedCat == null) {
            System.out.println("You have to select object that you want to edit");
            return;
        }
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/Animals/Cats/editCat/editCat.fxml"));
            Parent editCatParent = loader.load();
            Scene editCatScene = new Scene(editCatParent);
            Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            stage.setScene(editCatScene);
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("can't load an edit window.\n" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void deleteSelectedCat(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        ObservableList<Cats> selectedCat, list;

        list = tableView.getItems();
        selectedCat = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

        selectedCat.forEach(list::remove);
    }

    public void goToMainMenuCats(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
        Parent animalsMainMenuParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Animals/Cats/mainMenuCats/Cats.fxml"));
        Scene animalsMainMenuScene = new Scene(animalsMainMenuParent);
        Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setScene(animalsMainMenuScene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void goToEmployees(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
        Parent employeesMainMenuParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Employees/mainMenu/employeesMain.fxml"));
        Scene mainMenuScene = new Scene(employeesMainMenuParent);
        Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setScene(mainMenuScene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void goToAnimals(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
        Parent goToAnimalsMenuParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Animals/mainMenu/animalsMainMenu.fxml"));
        Scene goToAnimalsMenuScene = new Scene(goToAnimalsMenuParent);
        Stage goToAnimalsMenuStage = (Stage) ((Node) actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        goToAnimalsMenuStage.setScene(goToAnimalsMenuScene);
        goToAnimalsMenuStage.show();
    }

    public void goToStatus(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
        Parent goToStatusMenuParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Status/Menu/statusMainMenu.fxml"));
        Scene goToStatusMenuScene = new Scene(goToStatusMenuParent);
        Stage goToStatusMenuStage = (Stage) ((Node) actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        goToStatusMenuStage.setScene(goToStatusMenuScene);
        goToStatusMenuStage.show();
    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        initColumns();
        loadData();
    }


    private void initColumns() {
        catsId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ID"));
        catsName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Name"));
        catsRace.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Race"));
        catsGender.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Gender"));
        catsCoatColor.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("coatColor"));
        catsAge.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Age"));
    }

    private void loadData() {
        Database database = new Database();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Cats";
        ResultSet resultSet = database.execQuery(query);
        try {
            while (resultSet.next()) {

                Integer ID = resultSet.getInt("ID");
                String name = resultSet.getString("name");
                String race = resultSet.getString("race");
                String gender = resultSet.getString("gender");
                String coatColor = resultSet.getString("coat_color");
                Integer age = resultSet.getInt("age");

                list.add(new Cats(ID,name, race, gender, coatColor, age));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Can't select data from Cats\n" + e.getMessage());
        }
        tableView.getItems().setAll(list);
    }
}
```

Edit cat controller

```
package Animals.Cats.editCat;

import Animals.Cats.addCats.addCatController;
import Animals.Cats.retrieveCats.retrieveCatsController;
import Database.Database;
import Model.Cats;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class editCatController implements Initializable{

private  ObservableList<Cats> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private  Database database;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Cats> table;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Cats,Integer> idCol;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Cats,String> nameCol;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Cats,String> raceCol;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Cats,String> genderCol;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Cats,String> coatColorCol;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Cats,Integer> ageCol;


//    public void Save(){
//        String updateData = "UPDATE Cats set name=?, race=?, gender=?, coat_color=?, age=?"
//    }


    private void loadData() {
        list.clear();
        Database database = new Database();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Cats";
        ResultSet resultSet = database.execQuery(query);
        try {
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                Integer ID = resultSet.getInt("ID");
                String name = resultSet.getString("name");
                String race = resultSet.getString("race");
                String gender = resultSet.getString("gender");
                String coatColor = resultSet.getString("coat_color");
                Integer age = resultSet.getInt("age");

                list.add(new Cats(ID,name, race, gender, coatColor, age));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Can't select data from Cats\n" + e.getMessage());
        }
        table.getItems().setAll(list);
    }

    public void changeName(TableColumn.CellEditEvent editEvent){

        Cats cats = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        cats.setName(editEvent.getNewValue().toString());

    }

    public void changeRace(TableColumn.CellEditEvent editEvent){

        Cats cats = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        cats.setRace(editEvent.getNewValue().toString());

    }

    public void changeGender(TableColumn.CellEditEvent editEvent){

        Cats cats = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        cats.setGender(editEvent.getNewValue().toString());

    }

    public void changeCoatColor(TableColumn.CellEditEvent editEvent){

        Cats cats = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        cats.setCoatColor(editEvent.getNewValue().toString());

    }

    public void changeAge(TableColumn.CellEditEvent editEvent){

        Cats cats = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        cats.setAge((Integer) editEvent.getNewValue());

    }

    private void initColumns() {
        idCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ID"));
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Name"));
        raceCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Race"));
        genderCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Gender"));
        coatColorCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("coatColor"));
        ageCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Age"));
    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        database = new Database();
        initColumns();
        loadData();

        table.setEditable(true);

        nameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        raceCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        genderCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        coatColorCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());



    }

    public void test(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
        Parent animalsMainMenuParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Animals/Cats/retrieveCats/retrieveCats.fxml"));
        Scene animalsMainMenuScene = new Scene(animalsMainMenuParent);
        Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setScene(animalsMainMenuScene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void refreshData(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        loadData();
    }
}
```

retrieve cat fxml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
    <?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

    <AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.112" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Animals.Cats.retrieveCats.retrieveCatsController">
       <children>
          <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.29797979797979796" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <items>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                   <children>
                      <JFXButton layoutX="62.0" layoutY="93.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#goToAnimals" text="Animals" />
                      <JFXButton layoutX="62.0" layoutY="118.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#goToEmployees" text="Employees" />
                      <JFXButton alignment="CENTER" layoutX="62.0" layoutY="143.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#goToStatus" text="Status" />
                   </children>
                   <padding>
                      <Insets left="10.0" top="20.0" />
                   </padding></AnchorPane>
              <AnchorPane fx:id="tableRootPane" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                   <children>
                      <ButtonBar layoutX="138.0" layoutY="345.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="190.0">
                        <buttons>
                            <JFXButton mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#editCats" text="Edit" />
                            <JFXButton mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#deleteSelectedCat" text="Delete" />
                            <!--<JFXButton mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#goToMainMenuCats" text="Previous" />-->
                        </buttons>
                      </ButtonBar>
                      <TableView fx:id="tableView" prefHeight="345.0" prefWidth="417.0">
                        <columns>
                            <TableColumn fx:id="catsId" prefWidth="75.0" text="ID" />
                          <TableColumn fx:id="catsName" prefWidth="75.0" text="Name" />
                          <TableColumn fx:id="catsRace" prefWidth="75.0" text="Race" />
                          <TableColumn fx:id="catsGender" prefWidth="75.0" text="Gender" />
                          <TableColumn fx:id="catsCoatColor" prefWidth="75.0" text="Coat color" />
                          <TableColumn fx:id="catsAge" prefWidth="75.0" text="Age" />
                        </columns>
                         <columnResizePolicy>
                            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                         </columnResizePolicy>
                      </TableView>
                   </children>
                </AnchorPane>
            </items>
          </SplitPane>
       </children>
    </AnchorPane>


edit cat fxml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.112" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Animals.Cats.editCat.editCatController">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="table" layoutX="129.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="327.0" prefWidth="457.0">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="idCol"  prefWidth="75.0" text="ID" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="nameCol" onEditCommit="#changeName" prefWidth="75.0" text="Name" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="raceCol" onEditCommit="#changeRace" prefWidth="75.0" text="Race" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="genderCol" onEditCommit="#changeGender" prefWidth="75.0" text="Gender" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="coatColorCol" onEditCommit="#changeCoatColor" prefWidth="75.0" text="Coat color" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="ageCol" onEditCommit="#changeAge" prefWidth="75.0" text="Age" />
        </columns>
         <columnResizePolicy>
            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
         </columnResizePolicy>
      </TableView>
      <ButtonBar layoutX="372.0" layoutY="347.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0">
        <buttons>
            <JFXButton mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Save" text="Save" />
            <JFXButton mnemonicParsing="false" text="Cencel" />
            <JFXButton mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#refreshData" text="Refresh" />
        </buttons>
      </ButtonBar>
      <Button layoutX="262.0" layoutY="354.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#test" text="Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Error that i received:

Can't select data from Cats
no such column: 'ID'

Comment: Related: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-autoincrement/

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of code here, and you seem to be asking multiple things. I'll just answer the first (in general you should address one issue at a time in one question at a time, and you should create a complete example that does nothing else except demonstrate the problem at hand).

Your create statement defines a primary key column `Cat_id`:

```
String createCats = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Cats (Cat_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name varchar(255), race varchar(255), gender varchar(255), coat_color varchar(255),age int)";
```

however when processing the query, you try to retrieve a value from a column called `ID`:

```
Integer ID = resultSet.getInt("ID");
```

You need to make these match, e.g.

```
Integer ID = resultSet.getInt("Cat_id");
```

Comment: Now i have an another issue - INSERT INTO Cats VALUES ('test','test','test','test',123)
excecption at exec action
[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (table Cats has 6 columns but 5 values were supplied) Did i have to add id to every single object? I tought it will be added automaticly

Comment: @Trimekk As I said, you should only address one issue in each question. But what is the problem here? The error message tells you exactly what is wrong. And I don't see that SQL anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: The problem is i enter value for name,race,gender,coat_color,age.And program want from me to enter value of id,i thought it will be added automatically.    String createCats = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Cats (ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name varchar(255), race varchar(255), gender varchar(255), coat_color varchar(255),age int)"; this is String responsible for creating Cats table. Did i need to add an ID everytime when i adding some data into database? (i tought i need to add only name,race,gender,coat_color,age)

Comment: @Trimekk Again, **you should only address one issue in each question**.  You have an answer to this question. If you have other problems, you should post a new question. It should include the code that causes the issue (the code you dumped in comments here does not appear in your question, as far as I can see). I don't know why you don't use the insert statement you already have in the code in the question, which has the correct number of values. Please stop spamming the answer to your own question.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your database has auto-increment enabled. then just insert data into your database with sql "INSERT command" and later on display it with sql "SELECT command". Make sure to link your sql commands to your gui buttons in the controller.